# wikipedia page-to-page links by pageid

Tags: sql, wikipedia, pagerank

*What?:*
I'm trying to get page-to-page link map (matrix) of wikipedia pages by `page_id` in following format:

```
from1 to1 to2 to3 ...
from2 to1 to2 to3 ...
...
```

*Why?:*
I'm looking for data set (pages from wikipedia) to try out PageRank.

*Problem:*
At [dumps.wikimedia.org](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/skwiki/20120930/) it is possible to download **pages-articles.xml** which is XML with this kind of format:

```
<page>
  <title>...</title>
  <id>...</id>          // pageid
  <text>...</text>
</page>
```

that I will use for retrieving articles (`text`), then also base per-page data (**page.sql**) which contains some details about pages by `page_id` and last one that seems relevant to me is **pagelinks.sql** that contains page-to-page link records. Problem is that `pagelinks` table has following fields: `pl_from`, `pl_namespace` and `pl_title`.

*Idea:* Create temporary database, import `page` and `pagelinks` tables and create this matrix by using `pagelinks` table and retrieving  `page_id`s according to `pl_title`s. Possible solution:

```
SELECT pl_from, GROUP_CONCAT(page_id SEPARATOR ' ') FROM pagelinks
    JOIN page ON 
        pl_title = page_title AND pl_namespace = page_namespace
GROUP BY pl_from
```

or for getting map of "backlinks" (`to1 from1 from2 from3 ...`, not `from1 to1 to2 to3 ...`):

```
SELECT page_id, GROUP_CONCAT(pl_from SEPARATOR ' ') FROM pagelinks
    JOIN page ON 
        pl_title = page_title AND pl_namespace = page_namespace
GROUP BY page_id
```

*Question:*
Is there a place where to get this kind of matrix of page-to-page links by `page_id` so that I don't need to create it on my own ?
Or if not, is there any faster way how to get this kind of matrix than solution that I've pointed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think importing both tables into a database and using that is probably the easiest way to do this (and you don't need `pages-articles.xml` for that).

Another option would be to manually parse the two sql files without importing them to database. I actually created [a library to do exactly that in .Net](https://github.com/svick/Wikipedia-SQl-dump-parser/wiki).

Comment: Then maybe you need some indexes? I'm not sure whether the sql files create them.

Comment: There are indexes already, I think it's limited by speed of my disc... too bad that `page_id` is not part of `pagelinks` table already... never mind, thank you for help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, to parse XML files i guess you could try out this link:

http://haselgrove.id.au/wikipedia.htm

There's an approach, plus a couple of pre-made .m(MATLAB,OCTAVE) files that can clean your dump.
Also, there is a pre-processes dump in a .txt file. Though, it's pretty old. 2009 or so.